# MVC form is dirty when it is not

Tags: javascript, alert

I am updating a field using Ajax. Once the update is done, the field is still dirty causing the javascript alert "Are you sure you want to leave this page..you have unsaved changes" message. It's a simple ajax method:

```
function Save() {       
    var name = $("#Name").val();       
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/Method",
        data: { "firstname": name },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#messageToUser").find("label").html("Updated successfully");              

        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("in error");
        }
    });
}
```

From my googling, I found that I cannot block that message using the onbeforeunload, as that may have other effects on ajax functions etc.,. So what are my options?

Comment: how are you checking to see if something is dirty?

Comment: For divs with class names I do something like this:$(".dialogbtn").on("click", function () {           
            $("#isModelDirty")[0].value = true;}

Comment: So, I have a hidden field 'isModelDirty' which is set to true if an attribute or div values are changed

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting #isModelDirty to false in the success portion of the ajax call?